# Does $\lim_{n\to \infty}n(en!-\lfloor e n!\rfloor)$ exist?

Tags: real-analysis

Is there a limit for $$\lim_{n\to \infty}n(en!-\lfloor e n!\rfloor)$$
, and if yes, what is it?
I suspect this is to do with Gamma function and Sterling formula, but could not find a way out.

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to exist even without the factor $n$ in front.  I would expect the fractional part of $en!$ to bounce around in the unit interval.

Comment: You can just use Taylor: the fractional part of $en!$ will be $\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{n!}{k!}$. Bound this sum below by its first term and above using a geometric series comparison and see what you get. I think you will find the limit is 1.

Comment: @Ian thx I got it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a good answer from [OEIS sequence A000522](http://oeis.org/A000522) which is defined as $\, a_n = \lfloor e\, n! \rfloor \,$ and the entry also has the formula $\, a_n = n!\, e - 1/(n + 1/(n+1 + 2/(n+2 + 3/(n+3 + \dots)))) \,$
where the second term is what you want.